# jQuery setting background-image from an element source

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling with this one and it's more than likely me being silly but could someone help.

When you scroll in my example, a blue bar drops down and inside it will be the logo which is set from the pages actual `#logo`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xHPzd/1/)

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $(".topbarlogo").css({
        "background":"#000"
        });
    var _wrapwidth = $('#wrap').width();
    var _topbar = $("<div/>").attr({
        "id": "topbar",
        }).css({
            "width": _wrapwidth,
            "height": "50px",
            "background":"#43A6DF",
            "position": "fixed",
            "top":"0",
            "margin":"0 auto",
            "display":"none",
            "z-index":100
        });
    var _logo = $('#logo img').attr("src");
    var _topcontent = $("<div/>").append("<div id='topbarlogo' class='topbarlogo'></div>");
    console.log(_logo);
    $(_topbar).append(_topcontent);

    $("#wrap").prepend(_topbar);
    $(window).scroll(function(e){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) {
            console.log('>10');
            $(_topbar).slideDown();
        } else if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
            console.log('0');
            $(_topbar).slideUp();
        } else {
            console.log('0');
            $(_topbar).slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `.topbarlogo` just does not seem to load in the `background` whether I use CSS or an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
var _topcontent = $("<div/>").append('<div id="topbarlogo" class="topbarlogo"><img src="' + _logo + '"/></div>');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mCLsm/)

Comment: That works. But is there a way to get the image as a background image to `#topbarlogo`?